# What is the structure of a lipid and why is this example non-polar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polarity

Lipids usually consist of 3 fatty acids and 1 glycerol. I looked up what they look like[image]

So how is it not a polar molecule?  The $\ce{-OH}$ side has negative charge, and the hydrocarbon side chain has a positive charge.

Comment: How do you get that the side chain has a positive charge?

Comment: See Klaus's answer: Lipids are a class of biomolecule that are usually nonpolar **or** ambiphilic - they have a polar region (usually small, like the OH on cholesterol) and a nonpolar region (usually large, like the hydrocarbon part of cholesterol).

Comment: Why was his question downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

> Lipids usually consist of 3 fatty acids and 1 glycerol.

That's wrong. You're giving the definition of *fats*, which are just a subclass of lipids.

The structure in your question is the skeleton of **cholesterol** - without the stereochemistry.